# Export CRM 4.0 workflows to csv or txt

Tags: csv, dynamics-crm

Is anyone aware of a method to export the steps of a CRM 4.0 workflow to a csv file or text document? I need to document a lot of workflows, and I'd rather not do it all by hand!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can't be done. you can only export the workflow logic for editing in VS 2010.

[Exporting Workflow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334626.aspx)